# Lpc2148 UART0 - code doesnt enter the interrupt handler

Tags: linux, interrupt, lpc

Am using LPC2148 dev board and this is the code I have implemented

```
main() {
 initClock();
 initTimer0();

 led_init();  // init p0.21 
 rs232_init();

 while(1) {

 led_toggleState(); // toggle led
 delay(1000); // 1 sec delay

 }
}


void initTimer0() {
    T0CTCR = 0x0;   //Set Timer 0 into Timer Mode
    T0PR = 59999;   //Increment T0TC at every 60000 clock cycles
        //Count begins from zero hence subtracting 1
        //60000 clock cycles @60Mhz = 1 mS
    T0TCR = 0x02;   //Reset Timer
}

void initClock() {
  PLL0CON = 0x01;   //Enable PLL
  PLL0CFG = 0x24;   //Multiplier and divider setup
  PLL0FEED = 0xAA;  //Feed sequence
  PLL0FEED = 0x55;
  
  while(!(PLL0STAT & 0x00000400)); //is locked?
    
  PLL0CON = 0x03;   //Connect PLL after PLL is locked
  PLL0FEED = 0xAA;  //Feed sequence
  PLL0FEED = 0x55;
  VPBDIV = 0x01;    // PCLK is same as CCLK i.e.60 MHz
}

void rs232_init() {
    PINSEL0 = 0x05; // Enable UART0 pins
    U0LCR = 0x83; // 8-bit data, 1 stop bit, no parity
    U0DLL = 0x87; // Set baud rate to 9600 bps
    U0DLM = 0x01;
    U0LCR = 0x03; // Enable UART0
    U0IER = IER_RBR |  IER_THRE; // Enable THRE and RBR interrupt

    U0FCR = 0x07;

    VICVectAddr0 = (unsigned long)RS232_ISR;
    VICVectCntl0 = 0x00000026;
    VICIntEnable = 0x00000040;
}

void __attribute__ ((interrupt("IRQ"))) RS232_ISR(void) {
    int iir_value;

    iir_value = U0IIR; // read the interrupt identification register

    // Check if the interrupt was caused by a received character
    if (iir_value & IIR_RDA) {
        char rx = U0RBR; // read the received character
        U0THR = rx;

    // Check if the interrupt was caused by the transmitter becoming empty
    } else if (iir_value & IIR_THRE) {
        U0LSR; // read the line status register to clear the interrupt flag
    }

    VICVectAddr = 0x00; // Acknowledge the interrupt
}
```

In the main function, led blinks every 1sec and if any uart0, recv interrupt occurs, interrupt handler should be reached, but it is never reached
I transmit a char from my PC, the code should read it and transmit it back to the Pc, but it is not doing that.
Appreciate any help

Comment: My experience is mainly with TI and Microchip but on those PIC's you need to clear the Interrupt Flag when setting it up.  Do you need to do the same perhaps?  Just a thought.  PIC would be something like U1RXIF= 0, U1TXIF = 0 to set the Interrupt Flags initially and then these get reset after every interrupt.  Without those set the Interrupt won't fire.

Comment: Make sure that a ISP circuit, that often also uses P0.0 and P0.1, does not hinder the communication.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that we need to update the Startup.S in this way.
[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577). Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.